# What does $\Pi$ represent in cryptography?

Tags: signature, literature

I am doing a project in cryptography and while reading a tag generation algorithm for files, I got stuck with the meaning of $\Pi$. The screenshot of the algorithm is inserted below.

[image: Fig]

Here the *KeyGen* algorithm generates 1 public key and 2 secret keys and the *TagGen* algorithm takes a file $M$ (which is divided into $n$ blocks which is again divided into $s$ sectors) and the secret keys generated by the KeyGen algorithm. TagGen has to compute tags for blocks of the file $M$. I am stuck with how the data tags are computed here.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Multiplication - Capital Pi notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation)

Comment: @JMCF125: I don't think that's reasonable. It is perfectly plausible that it might have a specific meaning in cryptography. To use your example, if I see the word "literally" in a newspaper it probably means "figuratively", which is of course the opposite of what it means to a linguist.  Moreover, $\Pi$ is often used to denote a protocol, so its not unreasonable to check.

Comment: @figlesquidge, as CodeInChaos points out, a quick search would solve it right away. And indeed journalists are misinformed. `:)` Also, I don't ([didn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_protocol)) see what you mean (meant) by protocol; but $\Pi$ would make no sense as a protocol in this context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is standard mathematical notation and not specific to cryptography. The $\Pi$ symbol means *Product* in much the same sense $\Sigma$ means *Sum*. For instance,
$$\prod_{i=0}^2{u_i^{m_i}} = u_0^{m_0}u_1^{m_1}u_2^{m_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's the notation for the Encryption scheme in use, consisting key generation, decryption and encryption algorithms.
Open form:
Π = (Gen,Enc,Dec)

Comment: It _can be_ "notation for the Encryption scheme in use", but isn't here. $\;$